# overloading + operator is not working

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword

i am trying to overload the + operator. inside the overloaded function it is working,but when i am returning the object,its printing garbage value.

```
         mystring operator+(const char *q)
          {
          mystring r;
           int size=mystrlen(); //mystrlen() will return the string length
           int i=0,j=0;
           char pqr[25];
           for(;str[i]!='\0';i++)
           {
                pqr[i]=str[i];
           }

          for(;q[j]!='\0';j++,i++)
           {
                pqr[i]=q[j];
           }
           pqr[i]='\0';
           r.str=pqr;
           return r;   //when returning this,value is getting lost

          }


        friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os,mystring& p);
        };

      ostream& operator<<(ostream& os,mystring& p)
                  { 

                       int size=p.mystrlen();
                       char arr[size];
                       for(int i=0;p.str[i]!='\0';i++)
                       arr[i]=p.str[i];            
                       os<<arr;
                       return os;
                  }            
    int main()
    {
        mystring s="hello";
        mystring q;
        s=s+"hi";            //printing garbage value here
        cout<<s.str<<endl;
        cout<<q<<endl;

    }
```

expected output:hellohi
result gettig:garbage value

Comment: Have you overloaded `=`?

Comment: there are so many problems with this code!

Comment: Don't torture yourself like this. Use `std::string` or `std::wstring` and be done with it.

Comment: i suspect this is his homework, and he's supposed to learn about overloading operators.

Answer (score 0):

`char pqr[25];` is on the stack. Once the function returns it is out of scope, so `r.str` is not valid after the operator is called.